# Doing a sum of a column but keep getting timeout LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, timeout

From postgresql:

```
select client_id, sum(net_amount) from purchases
left join accounts on accounts.id= contracts.account_id
where purchase_date <= '2020-05-08'
and purchase_date > '2019-05-08'
group by client_id
```

This code only uses around 10seconds to execute, but the follow C# code fails:

From C#/.Net:

```
var clientPurchases = _context.Purchases
            .Where(m => accountIds.Contains(m.AccountId) &&
                        m.Date >= resultingStartDate &&
                        m.Date <= resultingEndDate)
            .ToList();
var sum = clientPurchases.Sum(m=>m.NetAmount);
```

This is the message thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOExcept
ion: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Socke
ts.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReader>d__100.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c.<Reader>b__6_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__1()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<>c__14`1.<GetElementFunction>b__14_3(IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Sum[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
```

I am trying to do a sum over around 10000 objects' net amount. Is there any other alternative which makes this possible?

Comment: The default timeout is 30 seconds.  Increase the timeout : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @jdweng Other than increasing the timeout limit, is there any other option? I mean on the C# code level.

Comment: Your c# version is loading all columns of the purchases where sql version only client id and the sum - you can change c# to calculate sum on database side, which should improve query execution time.

Comment: Try defraging the database.  The time is based on the size of the database, the amount of memory inthe server, the spped of the server, and the amount of data that is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `ToList` in the first query

```
var clientPurchases = _context.Purchases
            .Where(m => accountIds.Contains(m.AccountId) &&
                        m.Date >= resultingStartDate &&
                        m.Date <= resultingEndDate);
var sum = clientPurchases.Sum(m=>m.NetAmount);
```

Explanation: Before chaining the `ToList()` after the `where` clause, no queries have been executed on the sql server. By adding the `Sum` without the `ToList` you will calculate the sum on the sql server, without waiting to get on the C# memory space all the eligible Purchases and then calculate the sum on the IEnumerable.

Read more on this on [deferred linq to database execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution)

Comment: `var sum = _context.Purchases.Where(m => accountIds.Contains(m.AccountId) && m.Date >= resultingStartDate && m.Date <= resultingEndDate).Sum(m=>m.NetAmount);`
I just tried this and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: How many ids are in the accountids collection?

Comment: around 50 in the collection

Comment: Try to execute the original query without the left join. It seems like the execution plan first goes through the fate filters

Comment: If it takes too long, then try the left join solution from linq.

Answer (score 0):

Your linq code generates different SQL than your SQL code. You can use this linq to generate proper SQL query.

```
var result = (from purchase in dbContext.Purchases
               from contract in dbContext.Contracts
               join account in dbContext.Accounts on contract.AccountId equals account.Id 
               into temp
               from account in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where purchase.Date <= DateTime.Parse("2020-05-08")
                  && purchase.Date > DateTime.Parse("2019-05-08")
               group purchase by purchase.ClientId
               into g
               select new
                      {
                              ClientId = g.Key,
                              TotalNetAmount = g.Sum(x => x.NetAmount)
                      }).ToList();
```

Linq method chain version

```
var result = dbContext.Purchases
                       .SelectMany(purchase => dbContext.Contracts,
                                   (purchase, contract) => new
                                                           {
                                                                   purchase,
                                                                   contract
                                                           })
                       .GroupJoin(dbContext.Accounts, pc => pc.contract.AccountId, account => account.Id,
                                  (pc, temp) => new
                                                {
                                                        pc,
                                                        temp
                                                })
                       .SelectMany(pcTemp => pcTemp.temp.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                                   (pcTemp, account) => new
                                                         {
                                                                 pcTemp,
                                                                 account
                                                         })
                       .Where(pcTempAcc => pcTempAcc.pcTemp.pc.purchase.Date <= DateTime.Parse("2020-05-08") &&
                                           pcTempAcc.pcTemp.pc.purchase.Date > DateTime.Parse("2019-05-08"))
                       .GroupBy(pcTempAcc => pcTempAcc.pcTemp.pc.purchase.ClientId, pcTempAcc => pcTempAcc.pcTemp.pc.purchase)
                       .Select(g => new
                                    {
                                            ClientId = g.Key,
                                            TotalNetAmount = g.Sum(x => x.NetAmount)
                                    }).ToList();
```

This approach generates SQL like this

```
SELECT p.client_id AS "ClientId", COALESCE(SUM(p.net_amount), 0.0) AS "TotalNetAmount"
FROM "Purchase" AS p
CROSS JOIN "Contract" AS c
LEFT JOIN "Account" AS a ON c.account_id = a."Id"
WHERE (p.purchase_date <= DATE '2020-05-08') AND (p.purchase_date > DATE '2019-05-08')
GROUP BY p.client_id
```